# How to avoid 2 x with the same values adding up in a stacked panel graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, group, stacked-bar-chart

Thank you
I have a follow up question.

This is the information

```
df1<-data.frame(
  PPE=c("Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots", "Boots", "Overall", "Overall", "Lense", 
        "Lense", "Others", "Others", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots", "Boots", "Overall", 
        "Overall", "Lense", "Lense", "Others", "Others", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots", 
        "Boots", "Overall", "Overall", "Lense", "Lense", "Others", "Others", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask",
        "Mask", "Boots", "Boots", "Overall", "Overall", "Lense", "Lense", "Others", "Others", "Gloves", 
        "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots", "Boots", "Overall", "Overall", "Lense", "Lense", "Others", 
        "Others", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots", "Boots", "Overall", "Overall", "Lense", 
        "Lense", "Others", "Others", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots", "Boots", "Overall",
        "Overall", "Lense", "Lense", "Others", "Others", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Mask", "Mask", "Boots",
        "Boots", "Overall", "Overall", "Lense", "Lense", "Others", "Others")
  ,Choice =c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes",
             "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
             "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
             "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
             "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
  ,Farmtype =c("Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal", "Cereal",
               "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", "Forage", 
               "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Horticulture", 
               "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", 
               "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Horticulture", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", 
               "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", 
               "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "legumes", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms",
               "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms", "Root.farms",
               "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed")
  ,value=c(80.26,19.74,64.87,35.13,69.32,30.68,94.05,5.95,92.83,7.17,83.43,16.57,73.98,26.02,50.81,49.19,56.91,43.09,94.31,5.69,86.99,13.01,81.3,18.7,72.33,27.67,49.4,50.6,66.86,33.14,91.27,8.73,86.33,13.67,89.78,10.22,76.58,23.42,57.64,42.36,56.72,43.28,91.45,8.55,88.9,11.1,84.93,15.07,74.29,25.71,55.67,44.33,52.38,47.62,90.48,9.52,89.7,10.3,86.93,13.07,77.66,22.34,63.83,36.17,67.55,32.45,96.28,3.72,91.49,8.51,90.43,9.57,78.32,21.68,72.51,27.49,59.04,40.96,93.66,6.34,95.51,4.49,82.57,17.43,81.88,18.13,55.63,44.38,41.25,58.75,96.88,3.13,83.75,16.25,83.75,16.25)
)
summary(df1)
head(df1)
view(df1)
df2 <- 
  df1 |> 
  arrange(PPE, Farmtype, desc(Choice)) |> 
  mutate(order_val = ifelse(Choice == "Yes", value, NA_real_)) |> 
  fill(order_val)

#data frame for labels

labs <- 
  df2 |> 
  group_by(order_val) |> 
  filter(row_number() == 1)

# Create the grouped stacked graph
# I've simplified your version using `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar`
ggplot(df2, aes(x = fct_reorder(factor(order_val), order_val), 
                y = value, 
                fill = Choice)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(Farmtype ~ ., switch = "x", scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = labs$order_val,
                   labels = labs$PPE)+
  labs(x = "PPE", 
       y = "Value", 
       fill = "Choice") +
  ggtitle("Grouped and Stacked Graph") +
  # theme_minimal()
  theme_classic()+ 
  ggplot2::coord_flip()
```

The graph is [image]

I realized that the "Others" and "Lense" of df1$PPE have the same value for the Mixed farm as shown below.
[image]

This I think makes the graph that way. How do I make sure Lense and Others appear with their separate stacked bar in the graph?

Also, How do I make the values on the y axis appear in percentages like 0%, 50% and 100%?

I tried to get all variables to appear on the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mapping values on a discrete scale and afterwards assigning labels you could create a helper order column as the interaction of `Farmtype` and `PPE` after arranging your data in the desired order. Then use e.g. `gsub` to remove the `Farmtype` part from the axis label:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 |>
  group_by(Farmtype, PPE) |> 
  mutate(order_value = value[Choice == "No"]) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  arrange(Farmtype, desc(order_value)) |> 
  mutate(order = fct_inorder(paste(Farmtype, PPE, sep = ".")))

ggplot(df1, aes(
  y = order,
  x = value,
  fill = Choice
)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(Farmtype ~ ., switch = "x", scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = ~ gsub("^.*\\.", "", .x)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "PPE",
    y = "Value",
    fill = "Choice"
  ) +
  ggtitle("Grouped and Stacked Graph") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]